# Can't parse string to date format, keep getting null values

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, databricks

I have a date column in string. Date is as follows: SinkCreatedOn = 7/30/2022 5:21:55 PM

I am trying to parse to datetype using following code but always get null values. I have tried many different specific date formats i.e M/d/y as it says in new spark documentation

```
df = df.withColumn("test", F.to_date(F.to_timestamp(col("SinkCreatedOn"), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a")))
```

test returns null

I tried this code on a column that only included date and it worked. When timestamp is present it breaks.

Any help much appreciated

Thank you

[Picture of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIUcb.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `HH` which is for 24 Hr date format. Instead, use `h`. Please refer [SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

The following works:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["07/30/2022 05:21:55 PM"],
], ["SinkCreatedOn"])


df.withColumn("test", F.to_date(F.to_timestamp(F.col("SinkCreatedOn"), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"))).show()

+----------------------+----------+
|SinkCreatedOn         |test      |
+----------------------+----------+
|07/30/2022 05:21:55 PM|2022-07-30|
+----------------------+----------+
```

Comment: the padding isn't really reqd. `'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a'` will work just fine.

Comment: You are right. I tested and modified the answer. Thanks!